# How to make onmouseover image size relative to onmouseout img?

Tags: html, image, onmouseover, onmouseout

I am currently using onmouseover and onmouseout to shown a different image on mouse hover.

The onmouseover images have different dimensions to the onmouseout images so when the image is hovered over it changes the page layout.

here is an example of the code I currently have:

`<img src="images/image.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/image2.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images/image.png';">`

Is there a way of setting the onmouseover image to conform to the width of the onmouseout image and as a result not change the page layout?

(I am very new to all this so please bear with me)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that is first find your main `image` `width` and `height` dimensions

My main image `width` is `750px` and height is `500px`

So you just need to set `style` property of `width and height` for your `img` tag

It will set `width` and `height` for all images including the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` all three images will display with same dimesion

```html
<img style="width: 750px; height: 500px;" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1592134959663-4cdd34840e63?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"

onmouseover="this.src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1592101872812-cdbbe7912bfb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60';"


  onmouseout="this.src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1592081164105-70c567c6cfa2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60';">
```

Comment: Thank you, I am using percentage width to make the site scalable, I am struggling to get the correct percentage for each image, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide some more `code` so to get a better view

Comment: Sure, I am creating a catalog for my clothing brand, when you hover on the image it zooms into the design. I have used tables to lay the images out. I then wanted it so that when the document was reduced it started reducing the number of columns, from 4 then 3, 2 and 1 for mobile, for this I used `@media only screen and (min-width: 650px) {#one {display: none;}} ` of varying min-widths and max-widths to hide and show different tables at different viewport widths... (continued in next comment)

Comment: ...For the 4 column table I have managed to get the hover images working by editing them to be the same size as a containing `<th>` This falls apart however when moving down to another column level and it would mean I would have to make multiple images in different pixel sizes per table.